# Let $D(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \ a_n*z^n$ with radius = 1 such as $D(x) ∼ 1/(1-x)$ if x -> 1,x<1

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $D(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \ a_n*z^n$ with radius = 1 such as $D(x) ∼ 1/(1-x)$ when x -> 1,x<1

Show that $\forall {k \geqslant 1}$  ,  k natural number :

$D(x^k) ∼ 1/[k(1-x)]$     when x -> 1,x<1

I have no idea on how to answer this question,

Comment: Can you prove that $1-x^k \sim k (1-x)$ as $x\to 1$ ?

Comment: @PabloRotondo Hmm i dont know, is it right to say that : 1/(1-x^k) ∼ sum x^(k*n) ? You seem to mean that if 1/(1-x^k) ∼ 1/k(1-x) so we have D(x^k) ∼ 1/k(1-x) right ?

Comment: - " is it right to say that : 1/(1-x^k) ∼ sum x^(k*n) ?" :  No, that will not prove the equivalent because you just get a divergent series. Think about (1-x^k)/(1-x)...

- "You seem to mean that if 1/(1-x^k) ∼ 1/k(1-x) so we have D(x^k) ∼ 1/k(1-x) right ?"  : Yes. Do you see why ?

Comment: @PabloRotondo $1-x^k \sim k (1-x)$ as $x\to 1$ is ok at the limit, for the implication i don't see why, or maybe we get that D(x^k) ∼ 1/(1-x^k) immediately by D(x) ∼ 1/(1-x), and the equivalence 1/(1-x^k) ∼ 1/k(1-x) involves D(x^k) ∼ 1/k(1-x)